# PHP looping through an array and echoing selected items

Tags: php

I have an array returned from an api call. Sometimes it will be just one set and at others many sets. The example is below, taken for page "view source":

```
[objects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [stock] => 388
                            [voice_enabled] => 1
                            [region] => BASEL, SWITZERLAND
                            [voice_rate] => 0.00800
                            [prefix] => 61
                            [sms_rate] => -1
                            [number_type] => local
                            [setup_rate] => 0.80000
                            [rental_rate] => 0.80000
                            [group_id] => 25728319905588
                            [sms_enabled] => 
                            [resource_uri] => /v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/AvailableNumberGroup/25728319905588/
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [stock] => 593
                            [voice_enabled] => 1
                            [region] => BELLINZONA, SWITZERLAND
                            [voice_rate] => 0.00800
                            [prefix] => 91
                            [sms_rate] => -1
                            [number_type] => local
                            [setup_rate] => 0.80000
                            [rental_rate] => 0.80000
                            [group_id] => 25732565267448
                            [sms_enabled] => 
                            [resource_uri] => /v1/Account/MAMTE4MTHJNJRKODBIMD/AvailableNumberGroup/25732565267448/
                    )
```

There are 10 more such blocks.

This is produced by an api call from the following PHP file:

```
<?php
 include("connect.php");
 include("settings.php");
 require_once 'myapiprovider.php';
 $p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);
 $params = array( 'country_iso' => 'CH' );
 $response = $p->get_number_group($params);
 print_r($response);
 ?>
```

Instead  of print_r($response) I would like to be able to loop through the items and echo just the region and the prefix in a nice list.

How can I do this?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://php.net/foreach

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($response["objects"] as $i=>$v)
{
echo "Region: ".$v["region"];
echo "<br>";
echo "Prefix: ".$v["prefix"];   
echo "<hr>";
```

}

Comment: thank you but sadly it does not work. I just get Region: then nothing and Prefix: then nothing. The styling is there with lines and the line break but the array item is not printed.

Comment: foreach($response['response']['objects'] as $result) {
    echo $result['region'] .", " . $result['prefix'] . '<br>';